# How to add a controller in android to search in a video

Tags: android, video, controller

I am pretty new in developing apps for Android so I need your experienced help.

How can I add a video controller, a bar to search in the video lenght? 
I tried to add some code lines from android guide but I get blank screen

Here's a link 2 screen shots

http://www.wocmultimedia.com/screenshot1.jpg

http://www.wocmultimedia.com/screenshot2xml.jpg

the activity is named controlbar.java the layout  clip2.xml the videoclip  corsolex_1.mp4 and is set in res/raw folder

Thank you very much. Have a good day.
Angelo

```
public class controlbar extends Activity {
  @Override protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.clip2); 
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 
    Uri videoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + 
        "/" + R.raw.corsolex_1); 
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoPath); 
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)); 
    videoView.requestFocus(); 
    videoView.start(); 
  } 
}
```

layout clip2.xml

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
  <VideoView 
      android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
  </VideoView> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Giammarresi: What does "search in the video lenght" mean?

Comment: And please, post the code in here, you cannot expect others to read part of it from an Eclipse screenshot

Comment: @Aleadam: Sorry, I told I'm new so I supposed screen shot could better give a global situation view. I want to have a buttons to play, stop, pause, fast forward, rewind as well as a seeking bar to random jump in some part of the video. In this case the video is called corsolex_1.mp4 and is set in res/raw folder  the activity is called controlbar.java and layout clip2.xml follows the comments with code of both.

Comment: @Aleadam: public class controlbar extends Activity {@Override 
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
 //TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.clip2);

 VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

     Uri videoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.corsolex_1);
        
     videoView.setVideoURI(videoPath);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

    }

}

Comment: @Aleadam: this is the code of layout clip2.xml     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
        <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></VideoView>
        
    </FrameLayout>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a few buttons for play and pause, and a [`SeekBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) to set the video play position (using `VideoView#seek(long)` inside a `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`).

Since I don't see any Button in your code, I would suggest you to start by reading the dev guide first (e.g., the [handling UI events page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)) and trying first some of the tutorials ([here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)).

You can then try to apply what you learned to your project, and come back with more specific questions.

*And, BTW, click on my edit to your post so you can learn how to post the code in there* :)